# Excel VBA application event triggered twice

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I am trying to change active printer according to worksheet name when click on Quick Print button, however, the `App_WorkbookBeforePrint` event is triggered twice. Tried `App_WorkbookBeforeClose` also triggered twice. I have already changed the Error Trapping to Break on All Error, but it seems like no errors have occurred.

ThisWorkbook:

```
Private XLApp As CExcelEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Set XLApp = New CExcelEvents
End Sub
```

Class Modules:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
  Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookBeforePrint(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)
  MsgBox Wb.FullName
  assignPrinter
End Sub
```

Module:

```
Const printer1 As String = "Bullzip PDF Printer on Ne10:"
Const printer2 As String = "EPSONF7E8B5 (L565 Series) on Ne07:"

Public Sub assignPrinter()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim wsn As String
  Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
  wsn = ws.Name
  Select Case wsn
    Case "FGWIP"
        Application.ActivePrinter = printer1
        ws.PrintOut
        Exit Sub
    Case "Rework"
        Application.ActivePrinter = printer2
        ws.PrintOut
        Exit Sub
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Else case."
        Exit Sub
  End Select
End Sub
```

Update:

Use `App_SheetActivate` instead of `App_WorkbookBeforePrint` to change active printer and remove `ws.Printout` as mentioned by Matley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-created your modules and the only error I received was in the code *Debug.Print assignPrinter* in which I replaced with *assignPrinter*.

The rest of the codes works fine. *App_WorkbookBeforePrint* did not trigger twice. You can set a breakpoint in *App_WorkbookBeforePrint* then look into Stack to see which triggers *App_WorkbookBeforePrint* for the second time.

Comment: I tested with worksheet "FGWIP". It runs to `ws.Printout` for the first time and then goes to `Private Sub App_WorkbookBeforePrint`. Then it continues until `Exit Sub` and starts printing, then prints again one the same `Exit Sub` line.

Comment: It will print twice because you clicked Quick Print then issued ws.PrintOut. You need to remove ws.PrintOut or set the active printer on Workbook_SheetActivate event instead of when the Quick Print is clicked.